# random limited connectivity nmcli

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, dns

I have some strange behavior on my laptop connectivity to local wifi. Apparently with no reason and totally random, the connectivity gets limited. This happens on average once per hour. This is what nmcli shows:

```
stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ nmcli g
STATE                  CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected (site only)  limited       enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

To solve the issue it is sufficient to start again the network manager applet. Of course, this is only a temporary solution.
I tried to understand the origin of the issue by pinging at different IPs over the Internet. My dummy troubleshooting results:

- I can ping my gateway
- I can ping any IP address
- I cannot ping hostnames

So I guess the issue is related to DNS name resolution. How can I solve the issue? Here below, the resolv.conf contents and output of uname.

```
stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ uname -a
Linux stefano-Latitude-E7240 4.18.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 14:34:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Additional requested infos:

```
stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION       
wlp2s0  wifi      connected    FASTWEB-XE5.0GHZ 
eno1    ethernet  unavailable  --               
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:f4:bb:67:3b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:16:54:ba:71:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.206/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 84662sec preferred_lft 84662sec
    inet6 2001:b07:5d29:9741:49b8:1d36:d9df:f637/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 603064sec preferred_lft 84287sec
    inet6 2001:b07:5d29:9741:e11e:4a67:e846:1e/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::94bf:18ac:a222:89c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ sudo lshw -short -class network
[sudo] password for stefano: 
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
/0/100/19        eno1       network        Ethernet Connection I218-LM
/0/100/1c.3/0    wlp2s0     network        Wireless 7260

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 1 wlan      dell-wifi      unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth dell-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0           unblocked unblocked
15 nfc       nfc0           unblocked unblocked
17 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   stefano-Latitude-E7240

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

EDIT2:

```
stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ hostname
stefano-Latitude-E7240

stefano@stefano-Latitude-E7240:~$ nmcli device show wlp2s0 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Is your Wi-Fi unstable? Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli device`, 2. `ip addr show`, 3. `sudo lshw -short -class network`,  4. `rfkill` and 5. `cat /etc/hosts`. Please report to `@marmayogi`.

Comment: Should be okay now. @Marmayogi

Comment: Please post the output of the commands: `nmcli device show wlp2s0 | grep IP4.DNS` and `hostname`

Comment: Added information on hostname and DNS. @Marmayogi
Adding the public Google DNS server 8.8.8.8 seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you add Google DNS server `8.8.8.8`? Is your Wi-Fi connectivity stabilized now? @S.G.Rinaldo, please let me know.

Comment: From the gui of nmcli IPv4. So, basically from settings > wifi > settings.wifi.name > IPv4. Apparently the connectivity is now fine. But I interpret the 8.8.8.8 solution as a workaround rather than an actual solution. Also consider that I have other devices usually connected to the same wifi and they never shown issues with connectivity. @Marmayogi

Comment: I have similar problem in Debian 10. My "solution" is to run the command `nmcli networking connectivity check`, for some reason that brings connectivity from limited to full…

Comment: I have similar problem, showing `limited` connectivity, also lots of [RFK-CHK] error in dmesg. I think it's v2raya causing this problem, if I disable v2raya, and recheck connectivity, then it will show `full`, also no more dmesg errors. So this it's worth checking whether your VPN is causing this by disabling it and see.